# c# send more than a single request at the same time to the same page (ex: for a login )

Tags: c#, multithreading, http, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I saw that in order to send requests at the same time to a page (for example for a login 10 POST requests and get if success or fail for each request) I have to use asynchronous requests in c#. I saw some codes about asynchronous requests but they don't send for example 10 requests at the same time and I don't understand how to do this. I also tried to get codes to do this with threads but no results reached. Can you make an example for me that can do what I described?

Comment: You should at least make an attempt and show us some code of it and describe where you are stuck specifically. But I think a good direction to start would be looking at `Parallel.Foreach` [e.g. here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop). Then research about making a login request and parallelize them with the above mentioned loop.

Comment: A request is not blocking, only the response is blocking.  So you can send 10 request in a row.  So you only need a asynchronous response.

Answer (score 1):

ApiController - example method in controller

```
// GET: api/currencies
[HttpGet]
[ResponseCache(Duration = 60)]
public async Task<IEnumerable<GetCurrencyResponse>> Get()
{
    var currencies = await _currencyService.GetCurrenciesAsync();

    return currencies;
}
```

Fiddler - you can catch request by using fiddler app (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), select it from requests list, click "s", write 10 and click "Ok" button to send ten exactly the same requests.

[image: Fiddler]